# Syntax error with 'order' when using partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, partition-by

I am trying to follow some online examples in learning partition by in SQL Server. I am getting an error when I try to add in an order by to my partition by.

Here is the tutorial I am trying to follow:
https://codingsight.com/calculating-running-total-with-over-clause-and-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server/

This code works:

```
SELECT 
    Id, StudentName, StudentGender, StudentAge,
    SUM (StudentAge) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentGender) AS RunningAgeTotal
FROM 
    PracticeDatabase..Students
```

This code results in an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'order'

```
SELECT 
    Id, StudentName, StudentGender, StudentAge,
    SUM (StudentAge) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentGender ORDER BY Id) AS RunningAgeTotal
FROM 
    PracticeDatabase..Students
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate it. I've tried several tutorials to try to understand partitioning but every time I throw in the order by function I get an error.

I am using SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.18386.0) and Management Studio.
Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Looks okay to me. Maybe you are using a very old SQL Server version that didn't support running totals? (I don't know if that was ever the case; it's just an idea.) What SQL Server version are you using behind your SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: *"I am using SQL Server Management Studion 15.0.18386.0"* This tells us nothing about the version of SQL Server you are using (it's like telling us you have Office 2016 installed when asked what Windows Version you have). I suspect you are using a completely unsupported version of SQL Server; perhaps 2008 or 2008 R2?

Comment: A cumulative `SUM`, @DaleK . When you add an `ORDER BY` it changes the default scope to `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. Of course, a cumulative `SUM` of student ages is an *odd* choice.

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008. Thanks! I agree a sum of student ages doesn't really help anything. I am trying to learn SQL by following these online examples but even when I copy the code verbatim I'm getting errors

Comment: There's your problem, @erjabr , as I guessed. Windowed `SUM`s like that were added in SQL Server 2012. Get yourself onto a supported version of SQL Server; 2008 has been **completely** unsupported for over 2 years. SQL Server 2017 and 2019 are the only versions that are currently fully supported (2012-2016 are only in extended support).

Comment: Oh boy, I never would have found this by myself, thanks very much!

Comment: @erjabr thats one for the toolbox then, because once you're sure the syntax is correct then really the only other thing is the product version. Using an online tool like DBFiddle with a different database version is also a good check.